# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am really confused with the error it is showing. The following is a code to read multiple tiff images from a directory and convert them to a .mat. Apparently, the other codes that run the .mat file, need the file made with this code itself. The code is as follows

```
function data=VBSreadtiff(directoryName)
%  data=TPMreadtiff(directoryName)

% directoryName = 'data/XYt-071212';

dsep = CheckDirectoryName(directoryName);

files = dir([directoryName, dsep, '*','.tif']);

numFiles=length(files);

data.info = imfinfo(fullfile(directoryName,files(1).name));
dataType=CheckDataType(data.info);

data.img  = zeros(data.info.Width,data.info.Height, numFiles,dataType);
disp(size(data.img(:,:,:)));

for n=1:numFiles
    %disp(imread(fullfile(directoryName,files(n).name)));
    data.img(:,:,n) = imread(fullfile(directoryName,files(n).name));
 end


function dataType=CheckDataType(dataInfo)

if     dataInfo.BitDepth<=8
    dataType='uint8';
elseif dataInfo.BitDepth<=16
    dataType='uint16';
elseif dataInfo.BitDepth<=32
    dataType='uint32';
elseif dataInfo.BitDepth<=64
    dataType='uint64';
else
    error('dataSize %d cannot expressed in this machine',dataInfo.BitDepth);
end


function dsep=CheckDirectoryName(directoryName)

if exist(directoryName,'dir')~=7
    error('%s does not exist.',directoryName);
end

if strcmp(directoryName(end),filesep)
    dsep='';
else
    dsep=filesep;
end
```

The complete code(all .m files) of this can be found in the following link [Vessel Branch Segmentation - Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36031-vessel-branch-segmentation)
NOW, according to the author of this code he asked me to put this in the command window

> imgData = VBSreadtiff('C:\Users\karthik\Desktop\junk\Drivedb\DRIVE\test\images\');

now, once I execute the above in the command window, I am getting the following error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in VBSreadtiff (line 20)
>       data.img(:,:,n) = imread(fullfile(directoryName,files(n).name));

Requesting a big help. Have been suffering with this since 3 days.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the author: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/contact/237946

Comment: Check the docs on `imread`. Your current code requires imread to return a matrix of size `[width, height, 1]`. `imread` however may return a `[width, height, 3]` or `[width, height, 4]` matrix as well, namely for non-grayscale images. In this case, your code fails...

Comment: @sebastian is most likely right. Set a debug stop at line 20, and just execute the `imread(...)` part of the line. Then check the size of the output returned.

Comment: Yea...thank you @sebastian. I have figured out that error, but I am not able to make the [width,height,3] to [width, height, 1]. Any suggestions as to how to change it to 1

Comment: No, not really. Basically you'll have to figure out what format is expected to be contained in `data.img` in the remaining parts of this program/toolbox...